# being nice vs. being kind

Tags: meaning, british-english, quotes

In the TV series Doctor Who, in his last episode '[Twice Upon a Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twice_Upon_a_Time_(Doctor_Who))',  the 12th doctor says:

> Always try to be nice
> and never fail to be kind.

[full quote on wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_Doctor#Incarnation_12)

What is the difference between being nice and being kind?  Why does he view kindness as mandatory and niceness as optional?

I've already found some answers on the level of motivational posters and self help books, I'm looking for a deeper analysis.

Comment: I don't think this is really an English language question. _Nice_ is a notoriously vague word.

Comment: These can be found in any dictionary.

Comment: To be nice means to present a pleasant side to other people. To be kind is very similar, but a bit stronger, in that kindness carries a sense of being generous and helpful as well as mere pleasantness.

Comment: This quote hardly even implies there is a clear distinction to begin with: both clauses could be two sides of the same coin, or repeated for emphasis.

Answer (score 0):

"Nice" has to be taken as meaning "pleasant", as when you speak about a *nice day*, or a *nice person*. ([OALD, nice](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/nice?q=nice), [kind](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/kind_2)) The definition of "a nice person" by Sydney Smith ([A System of Rhetoric - Charles William Bardeen · 1884](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/A_System_of_Rhetoric/p_QAAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+nice+person%22&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover)
) makes the difference clearer.

[image]

It can be seen from this description that the word affords a characterization of the behaviour as it affects the person themselves rather than as it impinges  on others through deeds that involve a substantial personal interaction; there is however overlapping; for instance, sitting bodkin affects directly the confort of the person next to you, which is enhanced, but perhaps one does not consider such an attitude quite properly described by the adjective "kind"; one might be inclined to speak rather of politeness, and polite behaviour is considered to be part of what makes a person nice, not kind.

Comment: That seems rather an old-fashioned interpretation of the word, especially given the context. (And sure these are things a nice person could or even would do, but do they define niceness in a person? If you don't understand someone or knock over a glass of wine, you stop being nice? That's not very nice.)

Comment: @Joachim No doubt, in particular the "requirement" that a nice person should  be neither too tall nor too short sounds very odd today, but I think that the reader can understand that most of the characteristics still apply.  I'd say you mustn't knock glasses over too often nor make it a habit to not listen carefully to your interlocutors, and insofar as this is what could be the interpretation and a truer characterizationI agree with what you say.